# Is it possible to set a recurring reminder for an email in Google's Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I feel like I'm missing something simple here...
When creating a reminder it's simple to make it recurring;

1. Pick a date/time
2. Select "Does not Repeat"
3. Pick a repeat period.

However, when setting a reminder on an **email** I'm not seeing the "Does not Repeat" button.

I have to be missing something.  How do I set an email to come back once a month?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was shut down in April, 2019, and is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this feature is missing.

This is the box when you set an ordinary reminder: [image]

And this is the same box when you add a reminder to an email: [image]

So, seems like you're out of luck here.

On the other hand, I created an ordinary reminder with a link instead, and it's good enough for my case. It looks like this then: [image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done for links as well.  The reason I'd love the same functionality on emails is because I have a few running email threads with long distance friends.  It's easy to read back through what we discussed last time, reply to the email, and quickly catch up for the month.  Can't quite automate this with Inbox. :-/